Python: for loop is taking too long
I've prepared a code to make it work in Python. But it's taking too long to finish. I was using similar version of this in MATLAB, but it wasn't that slow.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Load the CSV file
csv_file = 'C:/Users/nad/Downloads/Yard/070/interpolated_points.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

# Extract the coordinates (assumed to be in meters)
X_coords = df['X'].values
Z_coords = df['Z'].values
Y_coords = df['Y'].values

# Define the cell size in meters
cell_size = 0.0048  # Cell size in meters

# Define the cube dimensions in terms of number of cells
depth_cells = 104
width_cells = depth_cells * 2
length_cells = depth_cells * 2

# Convert cube dimensions to real-world units (meters)
depth = depth_cells * cell_size
width = width_cells * cell_size
length = length_cells * cell_size

# Determine the bounds of the entire grid
min_x, max_x = X_coords.min() - width / 2, X_coords.max() + width / 2
min_z, max_z = Z_coords.min(), Z_coords.max() + depth
min_y, max_y = Y_coords.min() - length / 2, Y_coords.max() + length / 2

# Convert to integers
grid_size_x = int((max_x - min_x) / cell_size)
grid_size_z = int((max_z - min_z) / cell_size)
grid_size_y = int((max_y - min_y) / cell_size)

# Create the 3D grid with real-world coordinates for each cell
x_coords_grid = np.linspace(min_x, max_x, grid_size_x)
z_coords_grid = np.linspace(min_z, max_z, grid_size_z)
y_coords_grid = np.linspace(min_y, max_y, grid_size_y)

# Create 3D meshgrids for the x, y, and z coordinates of the grid
X_grid, Z_grid, Y_grid = np.meshgrid(x_coords_grid, z_coords_grid, y_coords_grid, indexing='ij')

# Load your GPR data matrix (assumed to have the same number of columns as there are points in the CSV)
gpr_data = np.loadtxt('C:/Users/nad/Downloads/Yard/070/gpr_data.csv', delimiter=',')

# Define the distance interval for GPR data, using the updated cell size as resolution
gpr_data_resolution = cell_size  # Set to cell size

# Initialize an empty 3D array to store the summed GPR data for each grid cell
gpr_grid_data = np.zeros((grid_size_x, grid_size_z, grid_size_y))

# Vectorized distance calculation for each point
for point_index, (x_point, z_point, y_point) in enumerate(zip(X_coords, Z_coords, Y_coords)):
    # Calculate the Euclidean distance from all grid cells to the current point
    distance_grid = 2 * np.sqrt((X_grid - x_point) ** 2 +
                            (Z_grid - z_point) ** 2 +
                            (Y_grid - y_point) ** 2)
    
    # Determine the row in the GPR data that corresponds to this distance
    gpr_data_rows = (distance_grid / gpr_data_resolution).astype(int)

    # Mask to ensure valid row indices
    valid_mask = (gpr_data_rows >= 0) & (gpr_data_rows < gpr_data.shape[0])
    
    # Pull the GPR data for the valid indices using gpr_data_rows, and set invalid to 0
    gpr_data_values = np.zeros_like(distance_grid)
    
    # Extract the GPR data for valid indices
    gpr_data_values[valid_mask] = gpr_data[gpr_data_rows[valid_mask], point_index]

    # Accumulate the GPR data for this point into the final 3D grid
    gpr_grid_data += gpr_data_values

# Now, gpr_grid_data contains the GPR data for each cell after summing all points' contributions

I tried vectorizing all and avoiding using the for loop, then I got memory issue. What can I do for it to make it much much faster? Should I not use Python?

Matlab uses a JIT, CPython does not (it is a slow interpreter). You can use Numba (a JIT) so to do the same thing than Matlab (even better actually). You can also use Cython. Alternatively, you can try to vectorize the operation further but not all code can be fully vectorized. I think a significant part can be here.

pdist of Scipy should help. Broadcasting too. For optimal performance Numba/Cython are better than vectorization.

Not sure if it matches your problem, but searching for nearest points is common in the GIS world. Perhas their solutions work for you as well? Here's another example.

Thank you so much! I could decrease the processing time from 120sec to 2.25sec with CPU and 1.59sec with GPU (CUDA on Google Colab) with Numba. I wonder if I try Cython, would it be faster? Because the actual dataset will be much bigger.

Thank you Saaru, I guess geopandas is not solution for my performance issue, but I will check it. It looks useful and interesting!
